# How to fetch in to textboxes, edit them and save them back to database?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a gridview and Textboxes in Form1. When Form1 loads it will load the data into Gridview from database. I have a selectionChanged event of Gridview from where the data goes into textboxes and Now my problem is I want to edit them in Textboxes and save them to database, but When I click on save button it is creating a new record in the database and gridview. How to fix this ?

Below is my code for SaveButton:

```
private void btnSave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Measurement", con);
    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    dr["CellNumber"] = txtCellNo.Text.Trim();
    dr["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    dr["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
    dr["Shirt"] = txtShirt.Text;
    dr["Pant"] = txtPant.Text;
    dr["DueDate"] = txtDueDate.Text;
    dr["Date"] = txtDate.Text;
    if (dr["CellNumber"] == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Cell Number");
    }
    else if (dr["CellNumber"] != "")
    {
        dr = dt.Select(" ID = " + txtID.Text)[0]; //updated here
    }

    try
    {
        da.Update(ds, "Measurement");
    }
    catch (DBConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Code for Gridview:

```
private void dgv_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.SelectedRows)
        {
            //Send the first cell value into textbox'
            txtLastName.Text = row.Cells["LastName"].Value.ToString();
            txtFirstName.Text = row.Cells["FirstName"].Value.ToString();
            txtCellNo.Text = row.Cells["CellNumber"].Value.ToString();
            txtDate.Text = row.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString();
            txtDueDate.Text = row.Cells["DueDate"].Value.ToString();
            txtPant.Text = row.Cells["Pant"].Value.ToString();
            txtShirt.Text = row.Cells["Shirt"].Value.ToString();
            txtID.Text = row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`da.Update(ds, "Measurement");` is inserting a new record because the `RowState` property of the row you are attempting to update is set to `Added` since you are assigning the cell values to a new row. You need to update the values of an existing row. Check [DbDataAdapter.Update Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325462%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) :

> When an application calls the Update method, the DbDataAdapter
>   examines the RowState property, and executes the required INSERT,
>   UPDATE, or DELETE statements iteratively for each row, based on the
>   order of the indexes configured in the DataSet

Try this :

```
private void btnSave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Measurement where ID = @ID",con);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",int.Parse(txtID.Text));
    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    da.Fill(ds, "Measurement");        

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCellNo.Text.Trim()))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Cell Number");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
           dr = ds.Tables["Measurement"].Rows[0];

           dr["CellNumber"] = txtCellNo.Text.Trim();
           dr["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
           dr["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
           dr["Shirt"] = txtShirt.Text;
           dr["Pant"] = txtPant.Text;
           dr["DueDate"] = txtDueDate.Text;
           dr["Date"] = txtDate.Text;

           cb.GetUpdateCommand();
           da.Update(ds, "Measurement");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


  }
```

Comment: It is showing error" Cannot Implicitly convert System.Data.DataRow[] to System.Data.DataRow. I tried to put the code in Save button as you said.

Comment: Ok I tried dt.Select as you said, Now it is good that it is not adding a new row, but it is not updating the changes when I click save button

Comment: It is giving me error saying System.Data.DataTable does not contain a definition for 'Tables' and no extension method 'Tables' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) at this Line dr = da.Tables["Measurement"].Rows[0];

Comment: @KiritiK thats a mistake, it should be ds not da. updating answer

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Now the edit mode is working, but throwing error when adding new record at da.Fill(ds,"Measurement"). The error is Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: @KiritiK Ok great. Please mark this as accepted and ask a new question as its not a good idea to overload questions here. I will help you out in a new question.

Comment: I posted the problem in new question. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the WHERE condition in your query

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Measurement WHERE ID = " + txtID.Text, con);
```

Comment: I am using Sql command builder for insert, update and delete. If I give ID as where condition, it is only loading data based on ID, but what I want is to update data based on ID if I am not wrong ?

Comment: dt.select() has no affect. I have update the code. Just have a look if I am doing it right ?

Answer (score 0):

What you should look at is the way you save into the db.

What is happening now is you are inserting a new entity/row in the db instead of updating the one you already loaded.

You are missing the primary key field. The ID. So it will always be a new entity to add not one that exists and needs updating.

Comment: You are right, but I'm not sure how to bind the primary key when I am trying to edit. It just adds a new ID as the ID Column in the back end is set to auto increment. I understand that some how I have to figure out to edit the data based on ID key, but I don't want to use combo box. What should I do ?

Comment: @KiritiK You just have to load the ID in the DataRow along with all the other data

Answer (score 0):

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Measurement", con);
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
dr = dt.Select(" ID = " + txtID.Text)[0];

if (txtCellNo.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter Cell Number");
}
else if (dr["CellNumber"] != "")
{
    dr["CellNumber"] = txtCellNo.Text.Trim();
    dr["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    dr["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
    dr["Shirt"] = txtShirt.Text;
    dr["Pant"] = txtPant.Text;
    dr["DueDate"] = txtDueDate.Text;
    dr["Date"] = txtDate.Text;
}

try
{
    da.Update(ds, "Measurement");
}
catch (DBConcurrencyException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: dr = dt.Select(" ID = " + txtID.Text)[0]; Syntax error: Missing operand after '=' operator. Thank you, now the edit mode is working but I am not able to add a new record when I click on save. It is throwing error as mention above when I try to add new record :(

Comment: for new row the method u mentioned above will work........ Just u need to check whether its **update** or **new mode**, on the basis of tht your code will change. For new insertion you require **"DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();"**

Comment: it says Missing operand after '=' operator. when adding new row with dt.NewRow();